# Why does my code not realise there is a } to close the constructor off

Tags: c#, class, constructor, curly-braces

I have been using Visual Studio Code for my C# code; however, it does not seem to realise that I have got a curly bracket '}' at the end of the constructor for my 'opponent' class. Please help me find a way to make it realise that I have done it correctly as far as I can tell!

Here is the class:

```
public class opponent
{
    public int hp = 20;
    public int PDmg = 3;
    public int KDmg = 3;

    public void Opponent(int lv = 1)
    { # red line error marker here
        public int level = lv;
    }
}
```

And here is the error message:

> } expected [miscellaneousFiles.csproj]

Please help!

I have tried changing the name and capitalisation of the method name but it has not worked so the case-sensitivity of C# is not the problem. I have also tried removing the word 'void' and it did not work either.

Comment: `Opponent != opponent`  C# is case-sensitive.

Comment: Also, constructors have no return types

Comment: I have tried changing the capitalisation and it has not worked

Comment: Remove the word `void`.  Constructors cannot have return types.

Comment: You should get a good book on C#.  I recommend C# in a Nutshell by Joseph Albahari.  Last C# book you will ever need.

Comment: I have tried removing the word 'void' and it has not worked.

Comment: You have a legit error, so it's not a matter of convincing the compiler that you've done something correctly. And your error has nothing to do with constructors or naming. It's because you're trying to declare a local variable with `public` (which is a class-level thing). Either move your declaration of  `level` to class-level declaration like the rest of your class members, or create a proper local variable by removing `public`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

double click on the error and it will take you to the place you have missed the brace maybe its not this code where you have got the error

From this line

```
public int level = lv;
```

remove public and its gonna work

Answer (score -2):

C# is case-sensitive language, so `Opponent` and `opponent` are not the same ;)

Comment: Yes, however using the capitalisation of the first letter of the class makes the method a constructor.

Comment: @dominicthorpe No, a constructor is defined as a class member without any declared return type and having the exact same name as the class. Capitalization doesn’t matter.

Comment: In any case, changing it to 'public opponent (int lv = 1)' did not work.

Comment: This has nothing to do with case-sensitivity, nor is it related to having (or not having) a constructor. It's a mistake with the local variable creation.